# How to add a font awesome icon in the submit button in Flask Wtform?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I saw this question everywhere and I tried it all.

I have a web appli made with Python Flask and Wtform.

I simply want to add an icon :

```
<i class='mdi mdi-arrow-right-bold-circle ml-2'></i>
```

in my submit button.

This is my code:

```
class NewCampaignForm(FlaskForm):
    
    name = StringField('Name of your campaign', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=100)],render_kw={"placeholder": "i.e. : Cold messaging to small businesses..."})
    submit = SubmitField('Next<i class="mdi mdi-arrow-right-bold-circle ml-2"></i>')
```

I tried Markup:

```
from markupsafe import Markup
submit_value = Markup ('Next<i class="mdi mdi-arrow-right-bold-circle ml-2"></i>')
submit = SubmitField(submit_value)
```

[image]

It didn't work. It always show the html code as label instead of rendering it as HTML and display icon.

I've seen there was another Markup from jinja2:

from jinja2 import Markup

It didn't work either :-(

Do you have any idea how to display this icon in my submit  button?

Comment: Hey, did you ever find a solution? I am getting the exact same result as you were getting.

Answer (score 3):

You can't put HTML into the submit button even with Markup, because WTForms will render the button value you passed as a `value` attribute:

```
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next<i class="mdi mdi-arrow-right-bold-circle ml-2"></i>">
```

In your case, you can just write plain HTML for submit button instead of use WTForms's submit field in the template:

```
<form method="post">
{{ form.name() }}
<button type="submit">Next<i class="mdi mdi-arrow-right-bold-circle ml-2"></i></button>
</form>
```